# how to check and match data in column1 inside table 1 with column2 inside table 2 and get the updated values in side table 3

Tags: sql, salesforce

how to check and match data in column1 inside table 1 with column2 inside table 2 and get the updated values in side table 3

table 1

```
ID name: status : age

1  john   F       28
2  peter  G       20
3  Roger  K       67
```

Table 2:

```
ID name: status : age

1  john   Y       28
2  peter  J       20
3  Roger  K       67
4  trump  U       120
5  Donald F       450
```

Table 3 should contain the updated values

```
1  john   Y       28
2  peter  J       20
3  Roger  K       67
```

I need to get the updated status of IDs present in table 1 in table 3 how can I do that.

Note: I am using exacttarget SQL activity and update and many more functionalities does not work so I need some work around> I have tried this but this does not work.

```
UPDATE
    1C-C1-MatchStatus_72hoursSubscribers
SET
    1C-C1-MatchStatus_72hoursSubscribers.current_status = B.current_status
FROM
   1C-C1-MatchStatus_72hoursSubscribers A
INNER JOIN
    a_query B
ON 
   A.current_status = B.current_status
```

Comment: @gurV thanks for editing this, I was trying to edit but somehow it was not working for me. Besides could you please assist me with this query.

Comment: Does table 3 contain a copy of table 1 data?

Comment: No, table three is empty. I am trying to match data within column "status" from table 1 and table 2 and populate the new status recorded under table 2 to table 3. does that makes sense?

Comment: Then why do you want to do update. Shouldnt you insert data in table3 based on table1 and table2?

Comment: how to insert updated status of IDs present in table 1 to table 3. *table 2 constantly updating their status so matching their status in table 2

Comment: Ok. Please try searching for Merge in salesforce.

Comment: actually what you want to do is called SCD1 implementation. Try searching for that too. I am sorry I didn't see salesforce tag earlier.